# Unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django 1.8.3 and Python 3.4.3

I know this has been answered many times, but none of the answers are specific to my situation and I am still learning Python, so I am having difficulty piecing a solution together to what is a common error.

I have a custom tag that applies division and float on two objects. This works as expected if the fields being divided don't have initial values of '0', which is what is producing a 'None' value.

What I am trying to accomplish is to filter out the None or ignore initial values of '0' and just return a simple string message or an integer of '0'.

```
@register.simple_tag()
def average(num1, num2):
    return round(float(num1 / num2), 2)
```

Here is a small snippet of one of my template fields and the tag that is performing the function.

```
<tr>
    <th>Q1</th>
    <td>{{total_sales.Q1}}</td>
    <td>{{total_campaigns.Q1}}</td>
    <td>{{total_ifs_signups.Q1}}</td>
    <td>{{total_traffic.Q1}}</td>
    <td>{% average total_traffic.Q1 total_sales.Q1 %}</td>
</tr>
```

And the error message:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
Exception Location: /Users/charlessmith/Documents/Development/nfy/reportly/reportly/dashboard/templatetags/simple_tag.py in average, line 8
```

As always; thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just implement a simple type/value check for `num1` and `num2`:

```
@register.simple_tag()
def average(num1, num2):
    if num1 and num2 and num1 != 0 and num2 != 0:
        return round(float(num1 / num2), 2)
    return 'Your error message'
```

Comment: Awesome!! I had my if statement formatted in the wrong order... :) Thank you for the quick answer; fixed my issue right away!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not add an if statement which checks for '0' or None?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work...it is very likely I didn't do it correctly.  Can you provide an example? Thanks.

Comment: Just a simple thing   

`def average(num1, num2):
    if num1 in ['0', None] or num2 in ['0', None]:
        return '0'
    return round(float(num1)/float(num2), 2)
`

Comment: I accepted another answer which I think came in at the same time as yours and I just noticed.  Thank you for taking the time to help me.